# how to add library to android studio not the single project

Tags: android-studio

I want to add library to my android studio, the only way that i know is through the gradle.build file like:
     implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
the problem here is that the volley library is added to the current project only, and if i created an new project i will have to write this line of code again and sync project, is there's any way to add the library to android studio itself so that any time i open new project i have no need to write this line of code and sync project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create one common build file where you put all library dependencies and  common dependencies build file is used app build file or other build file as apply plugin.
Ex: apply plugin: 'common_build.gradle'